# What event to get and display current slider value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I try to get and display current jQuery slider value into textfield, when slider changed. But what is event in JS to execute script? I have that script:

```js
function add_value_textarea(){
var sliderval = $("#slider").slider("value");
var txtarea = document.getElementById('mytextfield');
return txtarea.value = sliderval;
}

window.onclick = add_value_textarea;
```

It works when I click at all place in a document but not when click at slider. I know i can display value using slider div but I need it in textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `change` event of slider.

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  change: function( event, ui ) {
      $("#some").text(ui.value);
  }
});
```

With html

```
<div id="slider"></div>

<input type="text" id="some"/>
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YeATF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change) is what you're looking for. Specify a listener to the change event when you create your slider (or afterwards but I don't know why you would do that).
Also, you use jQuery, so you could change all that by this listener:

```
function(e, ui) {
    $('#mytextfield').val(ui.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#mytextfield" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
```

The difference of slide is that the value of the textbox will change as you move the slider (without releasing it). If you use change the value of the textbox will change only once when you release the slider.

Another difference is that if you just click the slider (without actually sliding it) the slide event will not trigger whereas the change event will.

So you got those 2 alternatives. Pick and choose :)